# Where to place an immutable function definition?

Tags: scala, package

I have a parser which is represented by a function:

```
type Parser = Array[Byte] => String
```

So I have a packages `com.pack.age.format1` and `com.pack.age.format2`. And for both of the formats I have its own parser:

```
val format1Parser = (ba: Array[Byte]) => {
   //...
}

val format2Parser = (ba: Array[Byte]) => {
   //...
}
```

which are stateless.

I'm in doubt about where to place such definitions. I had an intention to put them in package objects, but I'm not sure if it's an "idiomatic" usage of package objects.

Or maybe creating a separate object for that purpose would be better?

Comment: I'd go with either: 1) package objects 2) `object Parser` and put everything there.